# room entity class in kotlin generic

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-room

I am trying to create a generic class in kotlin that my generic property should be a Entity of Room Library (or data class because my Entities are data class ).

```
@Entity()
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int? = null,
    val title: String,
)

class MyGenericClass<T : isEntity>() {
    // This is the important part

}
```

how can I impalement that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to place a "annotated with X" constraint on a Kotlin generic type. If you're in control of Entity classes, just create a interface, make all your entities implement it, and use it as a generic constraint:

```kotlin
interface BaseEntity

@Entity
data class MyEntity(...) : BaseEntity

class GenericClass<T : BaseEntity> {
    // ...
}
```